# Migration request: Authorship of technical documents

Tags: discussion

I'm a moderator on [Academia](http://academia.stackexchange.com), and this question has been recently asked on our site: [Who is the author?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/7607/102). It has been suggested that it could be migrated to workplace.SE, what do you think?

Comment: I suspect this is going to come down to a question about protecting yourself against plagerism which is more in your court than ours.  If question gets improved and you still do not want it I can see migrating that question here.  But not the current version

Answer (score 6):

This seems more like a question that may require a lawyer than simply someone skilled in navigating the professional workplace; therefore, I'm not sure migrating this question would be good for our site.

However, the question isn't going anywhere, so we can wait and see if others think it could have value here.

Comment: I agree. The answer is either "ask your employer" or a complicated legal answer.

Comment: Not just a laywer, but also it's an "it depends" as sometimes corporations have policies for this and so it can vary quite a bit.

Comment: @beth- can you post that as an answer so people can vote on it.  If there is support for migrating, then we can migrate.  The post may also need to be rephrased so it isn't too localized.

Comment: Thanks for the answers/comments! I guess that for now, the question will stay closed on Ac.SE.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid this one is not just a "needs a lawyer" but an "it depends" which goes against our rules in the guidelines for posting.  It's too bad, I agree that the how-tos of publishing a paper from a workplace would be OK with us, but the problem here is that different companies do this guideline differently.  I can see cases where the "author" may not actually be the writer, but the company itself, or where there is a case that a named list of "contributors" may be required.  It has a lot to do with the nature of the business.